# "Pylint: Unable to import XXX" in a venv with python3.8 using vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am using Remote-SSH extension of VSCode to do code development on a python project in a Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V.

So I am SSH'd into the project which uses a virtual env.
The project structure is something as follows

```
.vscode/settings.json
build/
docs/
app/
---/src/file1.py
---/src/file2.py
---/src/folder1/file3.py
venv/
```

My settings.json has the following:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/sven/stackl_dev/venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/sven/stackl_dev/venv/bin/pylint",
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

So  I believe I am using the correct python executable and pylint.

However, my file1.py, for instance, does " import file2.py.
My file3.py, as well.

Pylint then throws the error "Unable to import "file2".
And this is the case for any import I do in whichever way.
Similarly, I als0 get a no-name-in-module error for some imports.

Any clue on how to solve this?
How do I solve this?